# Android - Service or IntentService?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-service, intentservice, android-application-class

I have an app that runs certain "long" process when it is **opened** or when the device is **booted**.

The process performs certain amount of downloads via the download manager, and when the process finishes it sends a broadcast event to the app, to capture some analytics.

As I understand, whenever the boot broadcast event is called, the `Application` class is intantiated (if not in memory already).

`Application` class is also initiated when the user opens the app.

Based on that, the code to run the proccess is placed inside `onCreate` method of the `Application` class. (the process starts a new thread from there)

However, it appears that the "long" process is taking more than the time-to-live of the boot broadcast receiver (about 10s?), so the app process is killed. Then a couple of seconds later, after the download is finished a second broadcast is sent and the app is started again calling `Application.onCreate` again, with some undesirable effects.

The process was expected to run in a single linear way and not calling again `onCreate`.

As this process happens only once, I was thinking on creating a `Service` to give more time to the app to stay alive. However the process depends on DownloadManager so:

1) Using `IntentService` won't work (as I understand) because the process is still killed after `handleIntent` returns. The process creates new threads so its tasks are async, and `handleIntent` method will return before the whole process finishes.

2) Should I create a `Service` which is simply 'alive' for some time and then is stopped after the process finishes?

3) As an additional question, if I have a running `Service`, will `Application` class be instantiated and kept in memory until the Service is stopped?

Comment: are you blocking `onReceive` method of your BroadcastReceiver for more than 10 seconds?

Comment: @waqaslam no, the BroadcastReceiver does nothing at all regarding this process, the process is managed from Application class.

Comment: Instead of doing it in Application's `onCreate`, I would suggest you to spawn an `IntentService` inside `onReceive` of your BroadcastReceiver. Doing so will not occupy main-UI thread because IntentService runs on a background thread. Moreover, (as an alternate) you may also make use of `JobScheduler` as it comes with some nifty features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do this only once, you should just create your own `Service`. When your app starts, call `startService()`. In `onStartCommand()` of your `Service`, start a background `Thread` that does what you want and return `START_STICKY` (This keeps your `Service` running until you stop it). When the `Thread` completes, call `stopSelf()` on the `Service`.

Of course, you can use `IntentService`, but that class is just an extension of `Service` that provides another layer of convenience for you. `IntentService` manages a pool of background threads and takes care of starting and stopping the `Service` when it runs out of work. This is probably overkill for what you need, but go ahead and use it if you want. The tradeoffs here are negligible.

NOTE: `<opinion>`For some reason, lots of developers seem to like certain "fad" solutions, like `AsyncTask`, `IntentService`, and Event Bus. There are plenty of other ways to solve problems. There is no "one size fits all" in software development.`</opinion>`

Answer (score 0):

You could still use an Intent Service, you just need to block while the background task is running. Implementation could work like this:

Put it in a service, an IntentService could work like so:

```
 public class DownloadIntentService extends IntentService { 

  @Override
  protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
     //get url or whatever from intent
     //kick off async code to start the download, something like eg:
      DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask(url);
      downloadTask.setListener(new Listener() {
          public void onComplete(Download download) {
              DownloadIntentService.this.notify();
          }
       }
       downloadTask.start()
       wait();

  }
```